# Customizing Google Maps info bubble

Tags: google-maps

Good Day

I have read various posts on Stack on how to customize the Google Maps info bubble that pops up when you click on the map marker.

Now all of those answers agree that this is the best way top go:

[Customize Google Maps InfoBubble](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html)

Now great and all, but how to you actually implement that example with your updated content into you own google map?

I mean I am using a wordpress shortcode that imbeds the google map like this:

```
[google-map-v3 width="920" height="550" zoom="12" maptype="roadmap" mapalign="center" 
directionhint="false" language="default" poweredby="false" maptypecontrol="true" 
pancontrol="true" zoomcontrol="true" scalecontrol="true" streetviewcontrol="true" 
scrollwheelcontrol="false" draggable="true" tiltfourtyfive="false" 
addmarkermashupbubble="false" addmarkermashupbubble="false" 
addmarkerlist="-25.845002,28.192291{}1-default.png{}Centurion 
Offices|-33.946918,25.562375{}1-default.png{}PE Offices" bubbleautopan="true" 
showbike="false" showtraffic="false" showpanoramio="false"]
```